# How to show other fields from foreign keys in a partial in views/layouts in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a navbar in a Rails app. Users of the app can be a member of multiple organizations. I'm trying to build a "context switching" menu, where they can select which organization they want to look at so they can focus on the stuff within that organization. Here's the structure:

1. `users` table: has an id and a display_name
2. `organizations` table: has an id and an organization_name
3. `user_organizations` table that links
   users and organizations together

In the `users` table, there's a field `current_organization_id`, which is a foreign key to an organization in the `organizations` table. In order for `current_organization_id` to be valid, the user/organization relationship must exist in `user_organization`. Okay that's the context. Next is the issue.

Right now in the app's navbar, I can show the `current_user.current_organization_id` just fine. But it's just an id, like 5, which is not helpful to a user. I'm really struggling to actually show the `organization_name` that corresponds to the `current_organization_id`.

*views/layouts/_header.html*

```
<header>
    <nav style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        <div style="flex-direction:row; display:flex;">
            <a href="/">
                App Name
            </a>
            <% if current_user.nil? %>
                <%= link_to new_user_session_path do %>Sign In<% end %>
                <%= link_to new_user_registration_path do %>Sign Up<% end %>
            <% else %>
                  <%= link_to "My Organizations", organizations_path %>
                  <%= link_to "Edit Account", edit_user_registration_path %>
                  <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do %>Log Out<% end %>
                  <%= current_user.current_organization_id.organization.organization_name%>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

*views/layouts/application.html.erb*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AppName</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render partial: "layouts/header", locals: {organization: @organization} %>

    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's what I've tried:

Doing `<%= current_user.current_organization_id.organization.organization_name %>` doesn't work. I've also tried passing in organization as a local variable for the navbar partial like this: `<%= render partial: "layouts/header", locals: {organization: @organization} %>`  and that doesn't help either. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone helped me figure this out, so I thought I'd post the answer here. I added this to my user model.

*models/user.rb*

```
  def current_organization
    @current_organzation ||= Organization.find_by!(id: current_organization_id).organization_name
  end
```

And then changed my header partial to have this line.
*views/layouts/_header.html*

```
<%= current_user.current_organization %>
```